# What changes has happening on APP KEY in Laravel 5 before using in openssl_encrypt function?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, hash, key

In **laravel 5** app in env appKey has set like this:

```
82sNt7h7vjhbOwzXLfoQQYcHxYTua1Se
```

I need to remake `Crypt::encrypt();` manually. So when i check and echo **key** in `openssl_encrypt` function show me something like this:

```
���I9d� V?r��U8�&���B$̌�83
```

And now i want to know about changes on key in laravel before using in **encryption** method.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
$key = (string)base64_decode($key);
```